# Extract unmatched files in directory using a text file

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have 100 files in a directory, and a text file that lists out 35 of these files.

```
####Directory 
apple carrot orange pears bananas

###text file
apple
carrot
orange
```

I would like to use this text file that has filenames and compare in the directory to get unmatched filenames into a separate file. So it will be a file that lists out like below:

```
##unmatched text file
pears
bananas
```

I know to do this by using find if the search term was a particular string but could not figure out this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that the text file contains a subset of the files in the directory. Also assume that the file is called list.txt and the directory is called dir1, then the following will work:

```
(cat list.txt; ls -1 dir1) | sort | uniq -u
```

#### Explanations

- The command `(cat list.txt; ls -1 dir1)` starts a sub shell, executes the `cat` and the `ls` commands
- The combined output is then sorted and `uniq -u` will picks out those that are unique (not duplicated)

I believe this is what you want. If that works, you can redirect into another file:

```
(cat list.txt; ls -1 dir1) | sort | uniq -u > list2.txt
```